# NullReferenceException was unhandles

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

goodevening everyone. I'm working with my codes and encountered this kind of error. How can I eliminate it?? Thanks guys!

[image]

```
Private Sub dgvAttendanceHistoryView()
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb;")
        conn.Open()
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT sms_text AS ProfID, sent_dt AS [Date/Time] FROM SMS_IN WHERE sms_text='" & dgvAttendanceHistory.CurrentRow.Cells("sms_text").Value & "'", conn)
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        dgvAttendanceHistory.DataSource = dt
        setColumnWidth()
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't show on which line it happens, but I'm betting it happens inside setColumnWidth()

Comment: It happens here! Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT sms_text AS ProfID, sent_dt AS [Date/Time] FROM SMS_IN WHERE sms_text='" & dgvAttendanceHistory.CurrentRow.Cells("sms_text").Value & "'", conn)
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter

Comment: Maybe [`CurrentRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow(v=vs.110).aspx) is null.

Answer (score 1):

From you comment I can say that either `dgvAttendanceHistory.CurrentRow` or  `dgvAttendanceHistory.CurrentRow.Cells("sms_text")` is `Nothing`, so you need to test for that possibility first.

I'd like to point out the fact that you should really be using Parameters in your query instead of concatenating strings, as this opens a door for SQL injection attacks.

Cheers